# Finding a good DB design for my project

Tags: sql-server, database-design, referential-integrity, inheritance

*I've posted this on stackOverflow but this might be a more suitable place.*

I'm really struggling to find a good DB design for my project using SQL server.

I've already implemented a few models which worked great till this point, but now that I need to add something extra I just can't find a good option and I'm stuck with it ATM.

I've supplied below 2 very simplified models (class diagrams) I've tried, but both models are not working well.

**1st model:** which I also prefer if it's possible to fix

[image: 1st model]

I should explain first that msg and action can have the same basic id (i.e 1) but when used with tabID or groupID as a composite primary key, it becomes unique.

Here you can see that `UserInput` is created using only the basic ID which creates a problem to save both a `Msg` and `Action` with id 1 for example.
Is there anyway around this? maybe a way to say that ya `Action` and `Msg` are extending `UserInput` but they define all the keys themselves?

**2nd model:**

[image: class diagram]

Each `Critical Point` is related to either a `Msg` or `Action`, but how can I define it since they have a different set of PK? I would like to keep referral integrity.

I would REALLY appreciate help on this issue.

**Update**

Maybe my only option is to use this?

```
UserInput
  UserInputID:   PK (autogenerated)

Action
  ActionID:      PK
  TabID:         PK, FK
  UserInputID:   FK

Message
  MessageID      PK
  GroupID:       PK, FK
  UserInputID:   FK
```

The question is can I make the `Msg` and `Action` extend from UserInput without taking defining his PK as part of their PK...

Comment: Please explain what is the relationship between `UserInput` and `Action`/`Msg`. Can a UserInput be related to multiple Actions/Messages? Or a `UserInput` is either an `Action` or a `Msg`?

Comment: UserInput is either an Action or a Msg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the comments you mention that a `UserInput` is either a `Msg` or an `Action` and not related to many actions or to many messages. The first model does not accurately describe this relationship.

You correctly identify that the problem is how to make `Action` and `Msg` "extend" `UserInput`. This is often called Supertype/Subtype pattern in database design.

I would make `(UserInputID)` as the `PRIMARY KEY` in both `Action` and `Msg`:

```
UserInput
  UserInputID   PK

Action
  UserInputID   PK, FK1
  TabID         FK2

Message
  UserInputID   PK, FK1
  GroupID       FK2
```

The rest of the tables would stay unchanged. This is the easiest thing to do, assuming that you have the freedom to define how the IDs are populated (for every new Action, a new UnserInput is inserted and the ID is used for the Action, too. Similarly for the `Msg` table.)
It still does not address all potential problems. A malicious or wrong update can have the database into some weird status, where a `UserInput` is both an `Action` and a `Msg`.

---

An altered design can overcome the issue by adding a `Type` column and some constraints:

```
UserInput
  UserInputType  PK
  UserInputID    PK
  CHECK (UserInputType IN ('A', 'M'))

Action
  UserInputType  PK, FK1
  UserInputID    PK, FK1
  TabID          FK2
  CHECK (UserInputType = 'A')

Message
  UserInputType  PK, FK1
  UserInputID    PK, FK1
  GroupID:       FK2
  CHECK (UserInputType = 'M')

CriticalPoint
  UserInputType  PK, FK1
  UserInputID    PK, FK1
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30682/discussion-between-liranbo-and-ypercube).